# A counterexample to theorem about orthogonal projection

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, examples-counterexamples, inner-products, projection

Can someone give me an example of noncomplete inner product space $H$, its closed linear subspace of $H_0$ and element $x\in H$ such that there is no orthogonal projection of $x$ on $H_0$. In other words I need to construct a counterexample to theorem about orthogonal projection when inner product space is not complete.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $H$ be the inner product space consisting of $\ell^2$-sequences with finite support, let $\lambda = 2^{-1/2}$ and put
$$
z = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \;\lambda^n \,e_n \in \ell^2 \smallsetminus H
$$
Then $\langle z, z \rangle = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda^{2n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n} = 1$.

The subspace $H_0 = \{y \in H\,:\,\langle z, y \rangle = 0\}$ is closed in $H$ because $\langle z, \cdot\rangle: H \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

The projection of $x = e_1$ to $H_0$ should be
$$
y = e_1 - \langle z,e_1\rangle\, z = e_1 - \lambda z = \lambda^2 e_1 -  \sum_{n=2}^\infty \lambda^{n+1}e_n
\in \ell^2 \smallsetminus H_0.
$$
For $k \geq 2$ put
$$
z_k = \sum_{n=2}^k \;\lambda^{n} \,e_n + \lambda^{k+1} \frac{1}{1-\lambda} e_{k+1} \in H_0. 
$$
Then $y_k = \lambda^2 e_1-\lambda z_k \in H_0$ because 
$$
\langle y_k, z\rangle =\lambda^2 - \sum_{n=2}^{k}\,\lambda^{2n+1}-\frac{\lambda^{2k+2}}{1+\lambda} = \lambda^2 - \lambda^2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda^{2n} = 0.
$$
On the other hand, we have $y_k \to y$ in $\ell^2$, so
$$
\|e_1 - y\| \leq d(e_1,H_0) \leq \lim_{k\to\infty} \|e_1-y_k\| = \|e_1-y\|
$$
and we're done because $y \in \overline{H}_0$ in $\ell^2$ is the only point realizing $d(e_1,\overline{H}_0)$ in $\ell^2$, thus there can be no point in $H_0$ minimizing the distance to $e_1$ because $y \notin H_0$.

Answer (score 12):

As I did not succeed to come with an example by myself, I tried searching google books for
["not complete" "orthogonal projection"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22not+complete%22+%22orthogonal+projection%22&tbm=bks&tbo=1).

I found a counterexample in the book Linear Operator Theory in Engineering and Science
By Arch W. Naylor, George R. Sell, pages
[289](http://books.google.com/books?id=t3SXs4-KrE0C&pg=PA289)
and [302](http://books.google.com/books?id=t3SXs4-KrE0C&pg=PA302). (BTW this was the first ever book on functional analysis I was reading as a student. Now I wish didn't stop somewhere halfway back then - it seems that it contains a lot of interesting things and I remember the style of the book as very readable.)

I will reproduce a brief version of their example below, but it is probably better if you have a look in the book.
I've kept the notation from the book, so $X$ is the noncomplete space (your $H$) and $M$ is the subspace (your $H_0$).

---

> Suppose that $H$ is any Hilbert space and $X$ is a dense subspace
> of $H$ that is not closed. Let $z\in H\setminus X$. We define
> $$M=\{y\in X; \langle y,z \rangle=0\}.$$
> This set $M$ is a closed subspace of $X$.

> Now choose $x_0\in X\setminus M$. We will show that $x_0$
> has no orthogonal projection on $M$.

> Suppose that $y_0\in M$ is the orthogonal projection of $x_0$.
> This means $y_0-x_0$ is orthogonal to $M$ and thus it is a scalar
> multiple of $z$. This would imply $z\in X$, a contradiction.

---

So now we only ask whether it is possible to find $H$, $M$, $z$,
$x_0$ as above.

The choice from the book I mentioned is the following:
$H=\ell_2$,
$X=$ the set of all sequences that have only
finitely many nonzero terms
$z=(\frac1{k^2})_{k=0}^\infty$
$x_0$ can be chosen arbitrary such that $\langle x_0,z \rangle \ne 0$.

Comment: Oh, you've posted this while I was writing... I wasn't notified. The example I produced is an explicit version of yours.

Comment: Well, +1 anyway, it's much simpler in the abstract.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: 'This set $M$ is a closed subspace of $H$.' Here you meant to say closed subspace of $X$, right? Also, could you please explain why, in the last paragraph, '$y_0-x_0$ is orthogonal to $M$' would imply it is a scalar multiple of $z$?

Comment: @lychtalent I have edited (so the post now says it is a closed subspace of $X$.) 
About orthogonality to $M$: W.l.o.g., let us assume $|z|=1$. 
Let $v\in X$ be any vector such that $v\perp M$.
Let $c=\langle v,z\rangle$. Then for $v'=v-cz$ we have both $v'\in M$ and $v'\perp M$.
Now $v'\perp v'$ implies $v'=0$. So we have $v-cz=0$ and $v=cz$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond! However, I don't get why $v'=v-cz$ is an element of $M$. If I introduce the set $M'=\{y\in H;\langle y,z \rangle=0\}$, then I see that $v'\in M'$, and clearly $M\subset M'$. I suspect that $X$ being a dense subset of $H$ would be used, but have not figured out how.

Comment: @lychtalent You're right again - and this shows that I wasn't careful enough when looking into this problem. However, your comments suggests that this could be finished if we know (or can prove) that for any vector $x$ and any subspace $M$ we have $x\perp M$ $\implies$ $x\perp\overline M$. I would suggest that we might [continue this in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19167/2022/6/30) - at least if you know how to use chat.