# Is there a canonical projector to from a vector space to a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $W\subset V$ be vector spaces. Is there exist a canonical way to construct a projector $\pi: V \to W$?

The same question for W is the kernel or image of some map.

Comment: It should be doable if you have an inner product.

Comment: Are they finite dimensional?

Comment: @copper.hat may be infinite

Comment: there is obvious way to do it not canonical in finite case

Comment: @Aspirin What you're thinking of probably works in the infinite case as well, but your choice of basis is going to matter.

Comment: Any continuity requirements?

Comment: @copper.hat no any requirements

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: $W$ is always a kernel of _some_ map [like $V \to V/W$], and the same goes for the image [$W \to V$].

Comment: You should make precise what you mean by *canonical*, as otherwise the question is pretty much unanswerable!

Answer (score 12):

Here is an example.  $\mathbb R$ is a vector space over the field $\mathbb Q$.  Also $\mathbb Q \subseteq \mathbb R$ is a (one-dimensional) subspace.  I defy you to "canonically" write down a projection!

Answer (score 5):

For general linear space I don't think there exist a canonical construction. But anyway you can proceed as follows. Take Hamel basis $\{e_\alpha:\alpha\in A_0\}$ of $V$. Complete it up to Hamel basis $\{e_\alpha:\alpha\in A\}$ of $W$, where $A_0\subseteq A$. Now define
$$
\pi: W\to V: \sum\limits_{\alpha\in A}\lambda_\alpha e_\alpha\mapsto \sum\limits_{\alpha\in A_0}\lambda_\alpha e_\alpha
$$
This construction is not canonical because it relies on axiom of choice. Because of the axiom of choice completion of basis is quite "random", and not canonical.

But if $W$ is a Hilbert space, there is a good procedure to get canonical projection. Consider orthogonal complement $V^\perp$ of $V$, then from theorem about orthogonal projection for each $w\in W$ we have unique $w_1\in V$, $w_2\in V^\perp$ such that $w=w_1+w_2$. So we define
$$
\pi: W\to V: w\mapsto w_1
$$
Note that "hilbertablity" is necessary, there exist inner product spaces for which you can't construct *orthogonal* projections on particular subspaces. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82499/a-counterexample-to-theorem-about-orthogonal-projection) you can find a counterexample, but anyway you can apply non-canonical construction (involving Hamel basis) to get some, not necessary orthogonal projection $\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

If I grant/believe for the moment the questioner's claim that there are no continuity requirements, although this is not the only point, the answer is "no", in the following sense. First, as remarked upon in other answers and comments, to have a "projection" is exactly to have a "complementary subspace". If we have a vector space $V$ and for *every* subspace $W$ we have a "canonically" associated complementary subspace, this entails quite a few things.

If/when the vector space is over $\mathbb R$, this allows us to choose/find an "orthonormal basis", and, in doing so, define an inner product.

Stopping short of seeing what else is entailed... I myself am content to note that we might as well have an inner product to begin, in which case _of_course_ we have canonical complementary subspaces.

Over fields other than $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, and in general Banach spaces (now starting to refuse to ignore topology) or more general TVS's, certainly things are less clear. A thing that has always been disturbing to me is Serre's (by now 50-years-old) discussion of Banach spaces over $p$-adic fields... so, conceivably, depending upon the questioner's ulterior purposes, there might be something non-trivial there, of interest.

Comment: Dear @paul garrett, Could you elaborate on your comment about Serre's discussion of $p$-adic Banach spaces? I'm not familiar with what you're referring to.

Comment: Motivated by looking at p-adic interpolation of zetas and p-adic modular forms, in the 1970s Serre proved some fairly surprising results about Banach spaces over p-adic fields, completely continuous operators thereupon. For example, I seem to recall that he showed that the strong dual of $\ell^1$ is again of the form $\ell^1$, but this may be wrong. A paper by Coleman in Inv. Math. 1997 cites two of the papers of Serre I'd vaguely recalled.

Answer (score 1):

What does *canonical* mean? Unless that's some sort of invariant there are obviously many ways to project a space to a subspace. For example, given $W = \mathbb{R} \subset V = \mathbb{R}^2 $, the projection matrix:

$P_a= \pmatrix{1&a\cr 0&0\cr}$ fixes the basis vector $e_1$, and maps $e_2$ to an arbitrary vector $a e_1 \in W$.

Which $P_a$ is canonical?