# Orthogonal completion in nonhilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ be some Hilbert space. There is the widely known theorem in functional analysis which states that for each closed subspace $H\subset X$ we have $H\bigoplus H^{\perp}=X$.
Now we do not suppose $X$ to be Hilbert space (but it is endowed with a scalar product). Is it true that there always exists such closed subspace $H\subset X$ such that $H\bigoplus H^{\perp}\ne X$?

So, I know that the completness of $X$ is important in the proves given in books, but how to build such closed subspace $H$?

Comment: This question makes no sense because for non Hilbert spaces you do not have definition of $H^\perp\subset X$

Comment: @Norbert You only need an inner product (called "scalar product" here, probably because in German it's called Skalarprodukt) to define $H^\perp$.

Comment: Yes, I meant $X$ is almost Hilbert, i.e. is not complete (euclidean?)

Comment: Pre-Hilbert is a common name. But note that that does not imply Hausdorffness for all authors.

Comment: @DanielFischer I thought OP talked about general Banach spaces

Comment: @Norbert Is this a duplicate? Surely this question is more general then the one you are linking to?

Answer (score 0):

The meaningful question is: Does every closed subspace of a Banach space X have a topologically complementary subspace. The answer to this is: if and only if X is Hilbert.

Edit: I misunderstood the original question. Examples of closed hyperplanes in pre-Hilbert spaces which do not have orthogonal complement are constructed here:
[A counterexample to theorem about orthogonal projection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82499/a-counterexample-to-theorem-about-orthogonal-projection). The point is that if a hyperplane $H$ in $X$ has an orthogonal complement $H^\perp=<u>$ ($u$ is the unit vector), then for each vector $v\in X$ one can define the orthogonal projection to $H$ by the usual formula
$$
p(v)= v- (u\cdot v)u. 
$$
However, in the linked post one finds examples of closed hyperplanes in pre-Hilbert spaces $X$ so that for some $v\in X$, the orthogonal projection to $H$ does not exist.

Comment: The question, and it is meaningful, is whether in a pre-Hilbert space $X$, we have $X = H \oplus H^\perp$ for all closed subspaces $H \subset X$.

Comment: Exactly. I want to understand if it is possible to build such $H$ expicitly (e.g. up to a chose of a Cauchy sequence that has no limit)

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: I see, I misread the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this works?

Starting with $\ell^2(\mathbb{R})$, let $e_i$ be the sequence with a $1$ in the $i$th position, and $0$ elsewhere. Then take $X$ to be the linear span of the $e_i$'s and some sequence $v$, where $v$ has infinitely-many non-zero entries - i.e. the subspace of all (square-summable) sequences with only finitely-many non-zero entries *and* some sequence like $\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$. Then $X$ is a real inner-product space, but it isn't complete.

Then, if we let $H = \textrm{span}( e_2,\dots,e_n,\dots)$ (i.e. we have left out $e_1$ and $v$), then the orthogonal complement is $\textrm{span}(e_1)$, and $v$ is not in $H$ or $H^\perp$.

It is quite possible I have made a mistake in this answer, but hopefully there is something worthwhile here.