# A counterexample to the orthogonal projection theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products, orthogonality

Prove that every incomplete inner product space $H$ has a closed vector subspace $H_0$ such that$H \neq H_0 \oplus H_0^T$

It's known that for complete inner product spaces, that is, Hilbert spaces, the statement is false, because for every closed vector subspace the equality holds.

I tried to find in the proof where's completeness is required, but it doesn't help me.

I've found a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82499/a-counterexample-to-theorem-about-orthogonal-projection), but there's only an example, but I need a general fact.

Comment: In fact, second answer in your link provides general construction :)