# Counterexample for Hilbert projection theorem with closed convex subset?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, examples-counterexamples, complete-spaces, projection

Of the few counterexamples to this theorem that I was able to find, including [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82499/a-counterexample-to-theorem-about-orthogonal-projection), none of them involves an incomplete prehilbertian space and a closed incomplete convex subset.

I have another example with the space of square integrable sequences and the subspace of finitely supported sequences which again, is not closed.

I'm in search of an example of **an incomplete prehilbertian space containing a closed convex subset which doesn't define a projector** (hence the subset must be incomplete).

I naively tried considering the prehilbertian space of finitely supported sequences with the $l^2$ inner product and my closed convex subset was those sequences that start with a $0$. But even though the completeness assumption is not met, the projection function is still well-defined since all you have to do to project an element is replace its first term with a $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the set of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with the $L_2$ norm.

Let $f(x) = \int_0^{1 \over 2} x(t) dt$ which is bounded and let
$C = f^{-1} \{1\}$ which is closed and affine (hence convex).

The element $0$ has no nearest point in $C$.

To see why there is no nearest point, first consider the solution in the completed space ($L_2[0,1]$). It is straightforward to see that
$f(x) = \langle \phi, x \rangle$ where $\phi = 1_{[0,{1 \over 2}]}$
and a straightforward computation shows that $\min \{ \|x\|^2 | x \in L_2[0,1], \ f(x) = 1 \}$ is $x^*={\phi \over \|\phi\|^2}$. It is clear that $\phi$ is not equivalent to a continuous function.

Hence $\|x^*\| \le \|x\|$ for all $x \in C$, and since $x \mapsto \|x\|^2$ is strictly convex, the minimiser is unique, so
$\|x^*\| < \|x\| $ for all $x \in C$ such that $x \neq x^*$.

Furthermore, since the continuous functions are dense in $L_2[0,1]$,
there are continuous $x_n$ such that $x_n \to x^*$, and hence we see that $\inf \{ \|x\|^2 | x \text{ is continuous}, f(x) = 1 \} = \|x^*\|$, but for any continuous $x$ such that $f(x) = 1$
satisfies $\|x^*\| < \|x\|$.

**Note**: As the OP observed in the comments, it is not necessarily the
case that the continuous $x_n$ are in $C$. Since $f(x_n) \to 1$ (as $x^* \in C$), we see that the sequence ${1 \over f(x_n)} x_n$ is continuous, lies in $C$ and converges to $x^*$.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on why 0 has no nearest point ? I'm trying with the negative inner product characterisation but all I could think of was that 2 is in $C$

Comment: I added a laborious elaboration.

Comment: Wonderful many thanks

Comment: PS: Although we know there is a sequence $(x_n)_n$ of continuous functions converging to $x^*$ in $L_2$, how do we know it can be contained within $C$, that is $f(x_n)=1$ ?

Comment: The sequence ${1 \over f(x_n)} x_n$ converges to $x_n$.

Answer (score 2):

Lemma:

> Let $W$ be a subspace of an inner product space $X$, and $x_0 \in X$. If there exists a distance minimizer $x \in W$ from $W$ to $x_0$, then necessarily $x_0 - x\in W^\perp$.

The proof uses the fact that $a \perp b \iff \|a\| \le \|a + \lambda b\|, \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.

Indeed, assume that $\|x_0 - x\| = d(x_0, W)$ and take any $y \in W$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.

$$\|x_0-x + \lambda y\| = \|x_0-\underbrace{(x - \lambda y)}_{\in W}\| \le \|x_0 - x\| \implies x_0 - x \perp y$$

Therefore $x_0 - x \in W^\perp$.

Let $c_{00}$ be the space of finitely-supported sequences with $\|\cdot\|_2$ norm. Consider the subspace
$$W = \left\{(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in c_{00} : \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_n}n = 0\right\} = \left\{(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in c_{00} : \left\langle (x_n)_{n=1}^\infty, \left(1, \frac12, \frac13, \ldots\right)\right\rangle = 0\right\} \le c_{00}$$

$W$ is closed in $c_{00}$. However, $W^\perp = \{0\}$.

Therefore, for any $x_0 \in c_{00} \setminus W$, the only candidate for the distance minimizer is $x_0$ itself, which is a contradiction since $x_0 \notin W$.